# Replace a question mark (?) with (\\?)

Tags: java, regex, replace, escaping

I am trying to define a pattern to match text with a question mark (?) inside it. In the regex the question mark is considered a 'once or not at all'. **So can i replace the (?) sign in my text with (\\?) to fix the pattern problem ?**

```
String text = "aaa aspx?pubid=222 zzz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "aspx?pubid=222" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( text );

if ( m.find() )
 System.out.print( "Found it." );
else
 System.out.print( "Didn't find it." );  // Always prints.
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to escape `?` as `\\?` in the ***regular expression and not in the text***.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "aspx\\?pubid=222" );
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/ZIwvs)

You can also make use of `quote` method of the `Pattern` class to quote the regex meta-characters, this way ***you*** need not have to worry about quoting them:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("aspx?pubid=222"));
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/aBI8Q)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is what i meant ... I need to replace the ? with \\? in the regular expression.

Comment: @Downvoter: I would love to know what is that you think is incorrect.

Comment: Seems like link share for https://www.ideone.com (See it) is no more valid. page shows "Solution not found"

Answer (score 4):

The right way to escape any text for Regular Expression in java is to use:

```
String quotedText = Pattern.quote("any text goes here !?@ #593 ++ { [");
```

Then you can use the **quotedText** as part of the regular expression.
For example you code should look like:

```
String text = "aaa aspx?pubid=222 zzz";
String quotedText = Pattern.quote( "aspx?pubid=222" );
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( quotedText );
Matcher m = p.matcher( text );

if ( m.find() )
    System.out.print( "Found it." ); // This gets printed
else
    System.out.print( "Didn't find it." );
```

Comment: I don't know if I would say that is the "right way". What if your pattern is (for the sake of argument) '?*\+*?' where the odd characters are literals. Would you rather see "\\?*\\\\+\\*?" or [[ Pattern.quote("?")  + "*" + Pattern.quote("\\") + "+" + Pattern.quote("*") + "?" ]] in your code? That said I would agree that using Pattern.quote could easily be described as the least error prone way to escape text for a regular expression.

Comment: If it's some kind of string that can change I would definitely will use Pattern.quote() , if that's part of the outer expression or one char only quote I would just escape it. In the original question, Brad need to quote a string, not one character.